# Can't Import CanvasJS into Java Project, Cannot resolve symbol canvasjs

Tags: javascript, maven, spring-boot, spring-mvc, canvasjs

I've been trying to draw a bar chart inside my spring-boot project using CanvasJS, but an error pops up saying `"cannot resolve symbol 'canvasjs'"` on the line importing CanvasJS service.

I'm following this tutorial to build the bar chart: https://canvasjs.com/spring-mvc-charts/multiseries-chart/

I'm working on IntelliJ Idea, the autocorrect suggested searching for JAR online or adding canvasjs as a dependency in my pom.xml. I've tried both options with no luck;

Here's the Import Line:

```
import com.canvasjs.chart.services.CanvasjsChartService;
```

and here's my pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>Campaign-Utils</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `CanvasJs` is a javascript library.
There are no java code in the library.
You need to create `CanvasjsChartService` service by own.
The model, service and controller is just some util to pass data from java code to ui (javascript).